# addFileAttachmentAsync with SharePoint or Onedrive

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I would like to attach a document from SharePoint Online to the mail with the office.js api.

The problem is that the addFileAttachmentAsync method just has an url as parameter so I can currently only attach public available files and not protected files.

In my app I can download the SharePoint file without a custom server as blob or base64.

Is it possible to use the html5 file api or can I reuse the SharePoint token somehow for addFileAttachmentAsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to attach files that are not publicly available.